# AttributeError: HelloWorld instance has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: qgis, python

Here's the code:

```
import sys,os
import win32api
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
import ctypes
from PyQt4 import uic


class HelloWorld:

    def __init__(self, iface):  

        self.iface = iface
        self.canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
        self.connect(self.ui.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.function)

    def initGui(self):       
        self.action = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/"), "&HelloWorld", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action.setWhatsThis("Configuration for test plugin")
        self.action.setStatusTip("This is status tip")
        QObject.connect(self.action, SIGNAL("activated()"), self.hello_world)


        self.iface.addPluginToMenu("HelloWorld", self.action)   


    def unload(self):    
        self.iface.removePluginMenu("HelloWorld",self.action)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)


    def function( self ):
        QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(), QCoreApplication.translate('HelloWorld', "HelloWorld"), QCoreApplication.translate('HelloWorld', "HelloWorld"))

    def hello_world(self):

        path = os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )
        self.optionsDialog = uic.loadUi(os.path.join(path,"untitled.ui"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
pass
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 164, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/User/.qgis//python/plugins\HelloWorld\__init__.py", line 15, in classFactory
    return HelloWorld(iface)
  File "C:/Users/User/.qgis//python/plugins\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.connect(self.ui.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.function)
AttributeError: HelloWorld instance has no attribute 'connect'
```

How can I resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

HelloWorld is not a subclass of any Qt class that supports the connect method. I suggest you use the "Plugin Builder" plugin to generate a template for you. This will get you started in the right direction.

Comment: I'm just trying to add a function to the action button.so that when you click to button  a specific action occurred. Maybe there's another way?

Comment: if I write here so that the error does not occur. but in this row specify the action on the button? QObject.connect(self.action, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.function)

Comment: Use: self.action.triggered.connect(self.function)